# beforeunload on Chrome

Tags: jquery, onbeforeunload

I have this code that will redirect the user to another URL whenever he/she closes the page. This is working on Firefox, IE, Safari, etc. but not in Chrome. It won't redirect the user to new URL.

Thanks!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e) {  
        location.href="http://google.com/";
        return "Before you leave, please take a look at this limited time offer.";
    });
});
```

Comment: You are lucky this works on other browsers, because it shouldn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it is what you are looking for, this will redirect user if he choices to stay on page:

### DEMO

```
var a,b;
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    if (b) return;
    a = setTimeout(function () {
        b = true;
        window.location.href = "http://google.com";
    }, 500);
    return "Before you leave, please take a look at this limited time offer.";
}
window.onunload = function () {
    clearTimeout(a);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there a way to redirect the user even if he/she doesn't choose any options on the pop up box yet?

Comment: No, it is no more possible on modern browsers

Comment: I see so I guess this is the only solution I have for Chrome. Thank you very much for this help!