# How do I load a specific url on refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, redirect, page-refresh

Let's say that someone decides to press F5 or the browser's reload button. Is that possible to open a specific url in the same tab?

Comment: Yes. But what tools have you? PHP, JS?

Comment: `Is that possible to open a specific url in the same tab?` You mean redirect them to another page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling key-press events (F1-F12) using JavaScript and jQuery, cross-browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424407/handling-key-press-events-f1-f12-using-javascript-and-jquery-cross-browser)

Comment: No it isn't possible... In fact there is surely some hacky ways but...

Comment: @A.Wolff what are you talking about?

Comment: @CodeiSir Sorry, i mean without handling it server side. If one way only client side, i'd like to heard about it. Now maybe i completly misunderstood OP's expected behaviour. Here is client side solution for specific behaviour but still not just for refresh one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23345263/1414562

Comment: @CodeiSir It's an HTML running JS and JQ.

Comment: @CodeiSir Please note regarding my previous comment link, jsFiddle doesn't like it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like posted in comment, if you display prompt, this is possible using following *ugly* hack:

```js
var a,b;
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    if (b) return;
    a = setTimeout(function () {
        b = true;
        window.location.href = "//test.com";
    }, 500);
    return "Now you will be redirected to new page if choosing to stay there...";
}
window.onunload = function () {
    clearTimeout(a);
}
```

Comment: Yep! It works nice, still having the syntax error on DW but Dev Tool has nothing reported yet. Great!

Comment: This is open to abuse.

Comment: @BrianPeacock So it deserves a downvote, right?!...??? And no, it cannot really be abused but sorry my english isn't as good as yours so maybe i misundertand what you are talking about...

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
// To check if someone pressed f5 or leaving the page

window.onbeforeunload = function () {

    //for changing the url

    var newUrl = "http://www.someurl.com";
    window.location.href = newUrl;
};
```

Comment: @Jim So you badly copied/pasted it. But anyway, wouldn't work for sure across browser

Comment: Try `window.location.assign(newUrl)` instead of `.href`.

Comment: @BrianPeacock But all (i guess) modern browsers block this behaviour, please try it on your side, is it working?

Comment: Again, I'm having Dream Weaver and it comes with a syntax error.
window.onbeforeunload = function () {var newUrl = "http://www.someurl.com"; window.location.assign(newUrl) };

Comment: The answer and you provide above did nothing at all.

Comment: @BrianPeacock The correction snippet you provide doesn't work.

Comment: @ all of you comment makers that was incomplete new here at stackoverflow :) but seems like A. Wolff transformed it in to a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8803019/4746328), the [ShortCut](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/) library is designed to handle keyboard button events, including F-keys and arrow-buttons etc.

However, I must say that the idea of redirecting people to another page or site when they think they are refreshing the page is not only bad practice, but open to abuse.

Comment: How does it help regarding user clicking browser refresh button?

Comment: See the other question and then check out the documentation - seems you can inhibit/enhance inbuilt browser functionality with option objects.

Comment: But that's only for shortcut keys, not user clicking on browser button

Comment: Did you even go to the ShortCut page?  Scroll down and you'll see the a list of valid keys - including the F-keys.

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm talking about **clicking on browser refresh button**. How is it related to any shortcut key?

Comment: You haven't understood that you can assign a function to any valid key with the ShortCut library - it's not just for shortcuts.  As to your question - perhaps you could edit your post with the code that you have already tried?

Comment: But i'm not OP :) And you still haven't understood i'm talking about refreshing the page by clicking on browser refresh button, not by pressing any key...

Comment: I'm sorry for any kind of confusion, i was thinking to be clear enough